# I Am Not Good with Boomerangs

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337).</sup>

---

> [I Am Not Good with Boomerangs](https://xkcd.com/445/),
>   But things I throw out sometimes return.
>   [I am Not a Ninja](https://xkcd.com/486/)
>   But have expertise, and for speed I yearn.
>
> [I Don't Own a TV](https://xkcd.com/1299/),
>   But I just added channels secure.
>   [I Don't Want Directions](https://xkcd.com/783/),
>   I've already taken the tour.
>
> [I Know You're Listening](https://xkcd.com/525/),
>   I'm keeping track.
>   [I Could Care Less](https://xkcd.com/1576/)
>   If you hate my quack.

**What am I?**

Comment: Ha, going all in with the FTC, with 6 titles :-)

Comment: @Phylyp Hoping there's an honorable mention for most xkcd titles.

Comment: Once my daily voting limit is over, there might be some good news for your reputation (I am currently seeing your rep at 9,995 :P)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are

> Stack Overflow

I Am Not Good with Boomerangs,
But things I throw out sometimes return.

> When a question is close (for being off-topic or badly formulated) it can be re-open later if it's edited and fits better in the site

I am Not a Ninja
But have expertise, and for speed I yearn.

> And you expect an answer as fast as possible

I Don't Own a TV,
But I just added channels secure.

> The recent addition of the [private channels](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/07/11/introducing-channels-private-qa-team/)

I Don't Want Directions,
I've already taken the tour.

> An experienced user doesn't need to  [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

I Know You're Listening,
I'm keeping track.

> This refers to the [annual survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/)

I Could Care Less
If you hate my quack.

> This refers to the april fools [Quack Overflow](https://blog.praveen.science/quack-overflow-stack-overflows-take-on-april-fool/)

Comment: Think about the second to last clue a bit more :)

Comment: OK, I think I got it this time

Comment: I like that interpretation! I was going for views keeping track of who "listens" to the question, but your idea is nice, too.

Comment: Thanks for that riddle anyway, it seems that it's hard to get understood here :)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you're

> ping

I Am Not Good with Boomerangs,
But things I throw out sometimes return.

> pings are sent to a remote server and sometimes they come back

I am Not a Ninja
But have expertise, and for speed I yearn.

> Everyone hopes for a fast ping

I Don't Own a TV,
But I just added channels secure.

> Maybe there didn't used to exist a way to ping SSL channels?

I Don't Want Directions,
I've already taken the tour.

> This isn't the trace route command; only the destination is important.

I Know You're Listening,
I'm keeping track.

> The ping command aggregates a set of pings and reports statistics when complete.

I Could Care Less
If you hate my quack.

> Perhaps a reference to "ping? pong!". Or maybe that "ack nack" sounds like a duck's quack?

Comment: Interesting try! However, I think you missed the clues "[I] have expertise" and "I've already taken the tour," and two other clues you did not seem to be able to fit. Incorrect, but good attempt! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be a

> College professor

I Am Not Good with Boomerangs,
But things I throw out sometimes return.

> Things teachers say in class might be repeated by students on exams or when called upon.

I am Not a Ninja
But have expertise, and for speed I yearn.

> Professors tend to be experts and want to cover the material quickly.

I Don't Own a TV,
But I just added channels secure.

> Many colleges now have online platforms, a relatively new development in academia.

I Don't Want Directions,
I've already taken the tour.

> Professors often already know the subject matter.

I Know You're Listening,
I'm keeping track.

> Professors might track attendance of who shows up (listens) to lectures.

I Could Care Less
If you hate my quack.

> Maybe because some professors don't care what students think of them?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! +1 for a well-written and interesting alternative answer.